# JSF/primefaces display image out of code - Image Location?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm using JSF with primefaces and want to display an image from java code.

I already saw the tutorial on http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dynamicImage.jsf

But I'm not clear on how I can get the path to my image file correctly:

Code:

Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
public class ABean {

    private StreamedContent bStatus;

    public ABean() {
        try {
            Boolean connected = false;
            if (connected == true) {
                bStatus = new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream(new File("/images/greendot.png")), "image/jpeg");
            } else {                
                bStatus = new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream(new File("/images/reddot.png")), "image/jpeg");
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public StreamedContent getBStatus() {
        return bStatus;
    }

    public void setBStatus(StreamedContent bStatus) {
        this.bStatus = bStatus;
    }
}
```

xhtml:

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{ABean.bStatus}" />
```

returns:

**java.io.FileNotFoundException: \images\reddot.png**

I would appreciate best practices on where to store my image when displaying it form code and how to do it.

Comment: And where is your image located actually?

Comment: My image is in WebContent/images/ - but I'm also open for a new structure to store my images for java code usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your images are in your web folder, you don't really need to use DefaultStreamedContent. I'd leave that **only** for images generated on the fly.

For your case, I'd just create a simple method that returns the image path (in your web folder) based on the boolean variable. Something like this:

```
public String getImagePath(){
    return connected ? "/images/greendot.png" : "/images/reddot.png";
}
```

And on the graphicImage, you can just reference that:

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{yourBean.imagePath}"/>
```

Note that you might have to adjust the graphicImage tag if your web context is not root.

**EDIT**
You can actually make this even simpler:

```
 <p:graphicImage value="#{yourBean.connected ? '/images/greendot.png' : '/images/reddot.png'}"/>
```

Just make sure to have a getter for the connected property.

Comment: Thanks for a best practice!

Comment: If I have image on the location like `D:/Images` then how can I get?  Can you pls give me any hints..

Comment: @Yubaraj unless your web server is configured to serve files off d:/Images you won't be able to just point p:graphicImage to that folder. You'll need to write a servlet that reads requests to a specific URL (i.e., /public/images) and maps those requests to the files in your D:/Images folder. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

Create your `StreamedContent` as follows:

```
bStatus = new DefaultStreamedContent(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("/images/greendot.png"), "image/jpeg");
```

When you are creating `new File()` this will be absolute path in your disk, not just in your application.

Comment: Thanks for concisely answering my q!